# Data structure with runtimes for insert and extract-max

Tags: algorithm, heap, big-o

What is a data structure that supports insert and extract-max in o(log n)?

Note that I do mean little-oh here. I know that a heap suppports insert and extract-max in O(log n), but is there a data structure which has o(log n) runtime for these two operations?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.  A max-heap is O(lg n) for both insert and extract-max, and that's the fastest it can be done.  The operations are asymptotically tight to lg n, hence O(lg n).  There is no other data structure that can beat that.

Comment: How can you prove this?

Comment: You can prove the efficacy of any one of the comparison sorting algorithms by showing a lower bound on the number of comparisons you have to do...but this is sounding more and more like homework...